# how to move up to find element?

Tags: jquery

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='text' name='A'>
<input type='text' name='B' readonly>
<input type='text' name='C' class='CCC'>
<select name='D'><option value=''>Select</option></select>
<input type='text' name='E' class='first'>
<input type='text' name='F' class='first'>
<button type='submit' name='BTN'>click</button>
</form>
```

how to use jquery to find above different elements? so far i only know .prev() but sometime it return back to me NULL/object when i use a lot .prev() to climb up.

any good way to learn?!

Sorry, let me put more detail on what i wish to learn here.

1). my way to get value from A, when click on button
$(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().val()
should have more better way right!

2). how to find previous element which is readonly?

3). how to find or get value from previous element whihc have class 'CCC'?

4). how to find or get different value which have same class of 'first'? i know there is something like :first or second but i keep getting error code, when i write something like $("input[class='first']:first").val() / $("input[class='first']:second").val()

Comment: If there is now previous element it would return null

Comment: i'm not sure, abhay kumar, but if i use a lot of .prev() or .next() sometimes it give me NULL, sometime it give me object object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the `form` element, and find any field in it, for example:

```
$(function(){

  $('button').click(function(){

    var c = $(this).closest('form').find('[name=C]');
    alert(c.val());

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

there are lots of ways to find an element ( `.siblings()` , `.find()` ,`.children()` ,`.prev()` , `.next()` , ...)

for example below code return element with CCC class that is in same level with $('input.A')

```
$('input.A').siblings('CCC');
```

look at this link may be helpful:
http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is of finding elements of a form, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someform").find(':input').each(function() {
       alert($(this).attr('name'));

     });
 });
```

working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NPNRh/)**